# (jQuery/JS) How to *set* a list item to be 1st in a UL or OL regardless of its original order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this working code here:

```
function portfolio() {
    $('#main-projects').children().toggle(function () {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        var projectname = $(this).attr('id');
        //alert(projectname);
        projectname = projectname.replace("li-", "main-");
        $('.main-details').hide();
        $('.main-stage').fadeOut(300);
        $('#' + projectname).delay(300).fadeIn(900);

    }, function () {
        //Haven't written callback yet, no worries.
    });
}
```

Works great already: when you click an LI (child of `ul#main-projects`) it finds the name of the hidden slideshow div by replacing the name of the LI's id, replaces "li-(name of project)" with "main-(name of project)" then shows that div.

What I also want it to do (and can't seem to find the solution to) is take the LI that's been selected and move it to be the first in the list to curate in a way for the slideshow that's just been shown above it.

I know how to grab an item number with eq(index) but I haven't found anything that forces a reorder without dragging and dropping. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insertBefore` to insert it before the first `li`:

- http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

Also take a look at this question:

- [Reordering of Divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558614/reorder-divs)

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming that your HTML is the same as you've described, then you can do it simply like this:

```
function portfolio() {
    $('#main-projects li').toggle(function () {
        var projectname = this.id.replace("li-", "main-");
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer').prependTo('#main-projects');
        $('.main-details').hide();
        $('.main-stage').fadeOut(300);
        $('#' + projectname).delay(300).fadeIn(900);
    }, function () {
        //Haven't written callback yet, no worries.
    });
}
```

See a simple demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/3zjSQ/