# HTML Custom Order?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking (for debugging purposes) for an example where text A appears before text B in HTML Code while B appears before A when being rendered in Browser.

An example that doesn't work:

```html
<h1>A</h1>
<h1>B</h1>
```

Preferably 2 examples one using JS and one not using JS at all.

One try:

```css
div.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  }
```

```html
<div class="absolute">
  This div element has position: absolute;
</div>

<p> test </p>
```

Comment: You can do it in CSS with `position: absolute` and then appropriate values for `top:`

Comment: But why the downvote, I clearly stated I'm new to HTML and didn't hear of `position: absolute` before and had no chance to discover it on my own...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but votes reflect the quality of the question, not the questioner.

Comment: and what's wrong with the quality of my question

Comment: i guess the downvoter thought you should have done a bit of research before the question.

Comment: It doesn't contain any code that we can help you fix, it's just asking us to write it for you.

Comment: position: absolute didn't work for me (they overlap), can you show example

Comment: It didn't work because you didn't set any position(s) for anything. A tutorial might be a more appropriate starting point.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: See [How can I reorder my divs using only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/220273/1264804) and [How can I reorder elements with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/558614/1264804).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean changing the orders you can try `order` property:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1#foo {
  order: 2;
}

h1#bar {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <h1 id="foo">A</h1>
  <h1 id="bar">B</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: `colum-reverse` the flex-direction would do I suppose.

Comment: @Michel yeah and there are multiple solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS `flex` with direction `column-reverse`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>A</h1>
  <h1>B</h1>
</div>
```

Or javascript, using `insertBefore()` to place B before A.

```js
document.getElementById("A").parentNode.
insertBefore(
  document.getElementById("B"),
  document.getElementById("A")
);
```

```html
<h1 id="A">A</h1>
<h1 id="B">B</h1>
```